# Can't connect to localhost MySQL server with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have Apache (with PHP) and MySQL installed and running on my Raspberry Pi. I've done some simple tests with PHP, and it seems to be working. And MySQL is working perfectly from the terminal, and even another computer.

I made this PHP file:

```
<?php

echo("Connecting");

$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "admin", "password", "test");

if ($connection->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error");
}

echo("Connection successful");

?>
```

Yet when I go to this page in my web browser, all I see is "Connecting". If I comment out the connection command, I see "Connecting Connection successful" in the browser.

It seems as if the PHP code stops running or hangs at the connection command.

Any ideas why I'm having this strange behavior?

Comment: Is the missing bracket at the end a copy-paste error?

Comment: Oh oops, yeah... I'll go edit it

Comment: Use die( $connection->connect_error); and check out the error msg

Comment: Try using `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1`. Sometimes PHP gets the wrong port for MySQL.

Comment: @C.Geek the problem is, it's never even getting past the connect line. It seems to stop right at that line.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma Just tried all four combinations: "localhost", "localhost:3307", "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1:3307" and none of them worked.

Comment: Check the phpinfo()  to make sure of the php version

Comment: @C.Geek It says I'm running "PHP Version 7.0.19-1"

Comment: Try changing 127.0.0.1 to localhost, sometimes you need to add permissions to each user to the host . So you should assign to 127.0.0.1 and localhost,or any other  names you use

Comment: Try adding these lines at the top: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: @C.Geek AH YES!!! You're a genius! It says it can't find the mysqli class. Thank you so much for your help! Could you put this as an answer so I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: Glad I can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these lines at the top: error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors',1);

Answer (score 0):

I hope You should do following

```
if ($connection->connect_error) {
    echo "Connection error";
}else{
    echo "Connection successful";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd add that later, but either way, I should be seeing more than the "Connecting" message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<?php
   $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "admin", "password", "test");

    if (!$link) {
        echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

   mysqli_close($link);
```

?>